# How to get "npm run dev" working after moving frontend of React/Typescript project made with Vite to 'client' folder?

Tags: npm, client, vite

I'm taking a frontend React/Typescript project made with Vite and trying to set it up so I can start adding a backend so it can be a MERN project. I took all of the files for the frontend and put them into a "client folder" and then made a separate "server" folder that for now is empty.

I'm just wanting to make sure everything on the frontend works right before moving on, but it tells me there's an error even finding a webpage on my localhost:3000 when I use "npm run dev" which was what I was doing up to now.

Here's how I reconfigured my "vite.config.ts" file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  root: './client',
  base: '/',
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000
  }
})
```

And here's how my package.json within the client folder looks at the moment:

```
{
  "name": "vite-number-conversion",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

I'm guessing it's mainly the package.json I need to mess with, but I'm not clear what I should do. Any advice appreciated!

Comment: can you share the directory structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the client folder, make sure that there are the following files: vite.config.ts,idnex.html,package.json.

Remove root and base of vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000
  }
})
```

and execute npm run dev.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I had added root and base because I asked ChatGPT and that's what it suggested I do. Goes to show it doesn't know what it's talking about...